# I'm Having trouble joining 3 MySQL tables, How do I improve my Syntax?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm attempting to join 3 different tables in my MySQL database. I've managed to join 2 tables before on limited columns, but I'm attempting to access all the columns in these tables so I can post the resulting data to a webpage. I feel I've tried every possible join combination from inner joins to Left Outer Join and Right Outer Joins. I've looked into doing Unions between the tables, but I've read that you need to have an equal number of columns in order for them to work, and the tables do not have the same number of columns.

Below is information on the tables I'm joining, and the syntax I've used while trying to query the database.

**Tables:**

```
Breeds -> 10 columns, Breed_Name is a Unique Key and links to the other two tables.
Lifestyle -> 11 Columns, Breeds.Breed_Name is a foreign Key to the Lifestyle.Breed Column
Temperament -> 10 Columns, Breeds.Breed_Name is a foreign Key to the Temperament.Breed Column
```

**MySQL Syntax**

```
Select B.*, L.*, T.*
From Breeds as B
Right Outer Join Lifestyle as L on B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed`
Right Outer Join Temperament as T on B.`Breed_Name` = T.`Breed`
Where B.`Breed_Name` = "German Shepherd Dog"
```

I managed to figure this out somewhat before, but then I changed something (don't even know what) and it all stopped working, and I haven't been able to get it back. But the odd thing was I was able to get information out of Breeds and Temperament using a Right Outer Join, but couldn't get anything out of Lifestyle regardless of what join I was using. And of course now none of it is working.

I don't have a firm understanding on the join types. I don't understand why we have different types. The information in my tables are different, and only match in a few columns because of foreign keys. If I could, I'd be doing Full Joins, as I think that's what I actually need, but MySQL doesn't do Full Joins (at last check). **How do I decide which type of join I need when I want all information in all tables?**

**For Future Reference:**

If I do manage to get this query to work, would I be able to scale up this query to as many different tables as I want? Just keep doing:

```
(join-type) *This table* on table1.`column` = table2.`column`
```

Or is it possible to need multiple join types during a single query? And if so, how do you decide which one to use?

**EDIT:**

I've played around with the query some, and if I remove the `WHERE B.`Breed_Name`= "German Shepherd Dog"` Then I get back to where I was when the code stopped working. But I still don't have access to the information in Lifestyle. What's wrong with my `WHERE` statement? Is it in the wrong place? I know you can do `WHERE` statements when you join tables . . .

**EDIT 2:**

(Just to give you guys an idea on how these answers are helping)

Something about the answers with single quotes in the WHERE statement is causing my whole page to disappear, which I think only happens when there's something incorrect about the syntax. If I take out the WHERE statement, Oddly Enough **ALL the answers work**. One answer suggests an **Inner Join**, one suggests a **Left Join**, one suggests just **JOIN**, and somehow, without the WHERE statement, they all work. What? One answer uses a STRCMP in the WHERE and that does seem to work, but I don't understand what that is (very well) and would prefer to use a simple WHERE statement. Is there any way to do that?

**Edit 3**

I don't know what happened, but now my Where statement is working, and multiple syntax versions are working. Is it possible for a Database to cache results and not show changes? I'm baffled by how before I couldn't get anything to work, but now nearly everything seems to be working? **The following 3 codes all work**:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM `Breeds` as B
Left JOIN `Lifestyle` AS L ON B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed`
Left JOIN `Temperament` AS T ON B.`Breed_Name` = T.`Breed`
Where B.`Breed_Name` = "German Shepherd Dog"

SELECT *
FROM `Breeds` as B
inner JOIN `Lifestyle` AS L ON B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed`
inner JOIN `Temperament` AS T ON B.`Breed_Name` = T.`Breed`
Where B.`Breed_Name` = "German Shepherd Dog"

SELECT *
FROM `Breeds` as B
JOIN `Lifestyle` AS L ON B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed`
JOIN `Temperament` AS T ON B.`Breed_Name` = T.`Breed`
Where B.`Breed_Name` = "German Shepherd Dog"
```

While I'm glad that it works, I'm frustrated because I don't understand how. And I thought that I had to use `Select B.*, L.*, T.*` when trying to source multiple tables, so why does a simple `Select *` work? And I don't understand why my WHERE statement is suddenly working when it wasn't before. Could it be because there was a subtle change in the syntax? There are now quotes around the table names where there weren't before.

**I look forward to reading further answers and I'm thankful for all help so far.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL this should get you there. Having no idea how your tables are actually structured, this is only an approximation.

```
SELECT *
FROM `Breeds` as B
JOIN `Lifestyle` AS L ON B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed`
JOIN `Temperament` AS T ON B.`Breed_Name` = T.`Breed`
WHERE B.`Breed_Name` = 'German Shepherd Dog';
```

Let me know if this gets you close.

(EDIT) Seeing your edit, use single quotes in MySQL to specify that your predicate is a string.

Comment: I tried to use single quotes, but it broke my query. See 2nd edit

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it is the simplest syntax that worked. Also, it looks like you could use some reputation points =)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to perform multiple `INNER JOIN` clauses to get your desired result.

Try this query:

```
SELECT B.*, L.*, T.*
FROM `Breeds` as B
INNER JOIN `Lifestyle` AS L
    ON B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed`
INNER JOIN `Temperament` AS T
    ON B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed`
WHERE STRCMP(B.`Breed_Name`,"German Shepherd Dog") = 0;
```

This should give you the results you need, if not let me know. If you're still having problems please set up a sample on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and add the link in to your original post so that we can test.

This image is a good reference for understanding the join types:
[image: SQL Join Venn Diagrams]

Comment: This seems to be working, but I have quesitons: 1.) What is STRCMP and how did that allow my WHERE statement to work? And why is there a 0 at the end of that statement? 2.) I understand the general concept of Joins, but I don't understand whether the information I want is in the overlap (inner) or outside left or right. Since all my info is related by the Breed_Name, would that make everything an Inner Join based on that relation?

Comment: 1. `STRCMP` is used to compare strings for equality, in some cases it's more reliable than using `=`. The `0` is what it returns if strings are equal; if the left string is greater than right it returns `-1` and `1` conversely. 2. Inner join is what you want because the intersection in the venn diagram represents a shared value between the two tables dependent on the `ON` clause, so yes in your case that relation is based on `Breed_Name` where `Breed_Name` is common between the tables involved in the `JOIN`.

Comment: Is there a way to work the WHERE statement without the STRCMP? Although it does work, I don't understand it well, and I feel I might mess it up in future attempts. Also, I received 3 different Join answers, and they all worked (without the Where statement). This doesn't help me understand joins better if they all work. There's a 2nd edit.

Comment: They'll all work without the `WHERE` statement because that doesn't restrict the `JOINS`, but instead restricts the final result set since you're specifying a predicate which any resulting rows must satisfy. The key factor that determines the criteria on which a `JOIN` is made is the type of `JOIN` and the predicate specified in the `ON` clause. It's just set theory from then. You could use `WHERE B.\`Breed_Name\` = 'German Shepherd Dog';` in your `WHERE` and it should still work fine if you don't want to use `STRCMP`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your data looks like, but `right join` doesn't seem correct here.  You want to start with the `breeds` table and keep all of those, along with matching columns from the other tables.  That is a `left join`, not a `right join`:

```
Select B.*, L.*, T.*
From Breeds B left Join
     Lifestyle L
     on B.`Breed_Name` = L.`Breed` left Join
     Temperament T
     on B.`Breed_Name` = T.`Breed`
Where B.`Breed_Name` = 'German Shepherd Dog'
```

Comment: I rarely use right joins...left is the way to go, +1

Comment: I tried your answer, but the WHERE statement broke my query. I've made a 2nd Edit.

Comment: @ShirleyDodson . . . Either `Breed_Name` is not a valid column or perhaps you just have no matching rows.